# Put a sequence inside an array in C

Tags: arrays, c, loops

I'm doing this exercise where I need to show to the user a list of sequence from 1 to 1000 and I have to make:

- A1=1
- A2=(A1 +4)+(A1-2), which is 2*A1 + 2

But I'm having a few troubles here where it doesn't shows me the numbers being inserted in my list (array)... It only displays me a "0". What am I doing wrong here? Can't find it...
Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int i;
    float a;
    float array[1000] = {1};

    a = 1;
    for (i = 0; i <= 1000; i++) {
        array[i+1] = 2 * a + (a + 1);
        printf("\nSequencia:%d - %.2f", i, array);
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `array[i+1]` will overflow `array[1000]` by two elements. The loop condition `i <= 1000;` should be `i < 999;`. I can't see why you need the `i+1` but even without that, the loop is one too many.

Comment: Print `array[i+1]` (or perhaps `array[i]`), not `array`?

Comment: Shouldn't `A2` be `2*A1 + 2` rather than `2*(A1 + 2)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `BUFFER_SIZE` macro to not overflow because of your condition "i <= 1000", array[1000] is between **0 and 999**, your code :`array[i + 1]`, will overflow at array[1000] and array[1001].

You are printing `array` and not `array[index]`.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 1000

int main(void)
{
    float a = 1;
    float array[BUFFER_SIZE] = {1};

    printf("\nSequencia: %d - %.2f", 0, array[0]);
    for (int i = 1; i < (BUFFER_SIZE - 1); i++) {
        //Maybe you are looking for :  a = 2 * a + (a + 1);
        array[i] = 2 * a + (a + 1); //Then : array[i] = a;
        printf("\nSequencia: %d - %.2f", i, array[i]);
    }
    system("pause");
        return 0;
}
```

You may [not be able to print everything](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types) with float, so you should use bigger types as **double** or **long double** (*extreme case : strings*).

Doing my best with my english level sorry ^^.

Comment: Still uses `a`, which is wrong

Comment: The loop would be better as `for (int i = 0; i < BUFFER_SIZE; i++)`. There is no reason to define and initialise `i` somewhere else.

Comment: @ikegami explain please, you are just telling people are wrong but you don't help them.

Comment: @WeatherVane done, i personally use int i = 0; outside of for loop if he need to use it later.

Comment: The correct formula is in the OP

Answer (score 1):

- You access more elements of the array than the array has.
- You use `a` instead of the correct value.
- The calculation is entirely different than one you said it should be.
- You print `array` instead of `array[i]`.

Enable your compiler's warnings!!! It would have caught some of these.

Fixed:

```c
size_t n = 1000;

float array[n];

array[0] = 1;
printf( "%zu - %f\n", 0 + 1, array[ 0 ] );

for ( size_t i = 1; i < n; ++i ) {
   array[ i ] = 2 * array[ i - 1 ] + 2;
   printf( "%zu - %f\n", i + 1, array[ i ] );
}
```

There's a final problem: The 1000th number of the sequence will be extremely large. Given `a[i]=2*a[i-1]`, the 1000th number would be 2<sup>999</sup>. You have `a[i]=2*a[i-1]+2` which is even larger. These are *huge* numbers. For comparison, there are about 10<sup>80</sup> ≈ 2<sup>266</sup> atoms in the visible universe.

So huge, in fact, that numbers that large can't be stored in a `float` on an x86 or x86-64. Moving to larger type could help, but it won't give the precision needed. Therefore, you'll need an arbitrary precision library.